# How to draw custom line on MKMapview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been searching for a way to draw a custom line, but the only help I can find is how to draw lines with an UIColor.

I want to draw a straight line but not just with a color. I want the appearance of the line to be customizable.

(So right now I can draw lines between 2 points, but not the line I want)

The line I want got straight 45 degree lines on it, and it's grey and black.

Anybody can help?

The line looks like this, I'm also thinking that I could stretch this image, but if I stretch it, it will look kinda weird.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want a gradient? Or am I off my hinges?

Comment: Are you saying you want to draw a line between two point and on that, you want to have 45 degree lines with alternating gray and black color?  Add on some more explanations and someone will be able to help

Comment: I have added an example of the line :)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add image then? I'm new developer so I don't know other way to do it. Only OpenGL with texturing, but there is no need to use openGL. So my suggestion is to add image.

Comment: If I add an image, I wont be able to resize the line. I can have a very long line, and then cut it. But then I will have scale problems.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like what your looking for is the [MKPolylineView Class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKPolylineView_class/Reference/Reference.html). You assign it a polyline which contains the points in your line. Since the polyline view is an [MKOverlayPathView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlayPathView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKOverlayPathView) you can set the stroke and fill colors.

Since it's also a UIView subclass you can manipulate the appearance even further by grabing the views layer property and adding gradients, shadows, masks, etc.

Is there a specific effect that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I have been using the MKPolyLineView. But you are probably right, I maybe have to go through all the hazzle with CALayer properties. But if there is a more elegant solution, I would rather use that, thanks.