# Interconnecting two annotations by a straight line in MkMapView

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, mkannotationview

Is any way to connecting two annotations in MkMapView by a straight line. Means it should look like this.[image]

I have gone through some tutorials in which they use java script to find route between 2 points even we can't draw routes between 2 continents separated by water. How can I implement this??

Comment: May be it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262804/how-to-draw-custom-line-on-mkmapview

Comment: Try by adding an overlay of MKPolyline on MkMapView. And then implement the delegate method viewForOverlay to set polyline display properties.

Comment: Try this guide: http://blog.robkerr.com/adding-a-mkpolyline-overlay-using-swift-to-an-ios-mapkit-map/